# Using callUDF to create a method that chains UDF calls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I monkey patched the `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` class to add a `chainUDF` method.  It works well for udfs that don't take arguments and I need help to make it generic for udfs that take arguments.

Here's the current `chainUDF` method definition.

```
object ColumnExt {

  implicit class ColumnMethods(c: Column) {

    def chainUDF(udfName: String): Column = {
      callUDF(udfName, c)
    }

  }

}
```

Here's the `chainUDF` method in action.

```
def appendZ(s: String): String = {
  s"${s}Z"
}

spark.udf.register("appendZUdf", appendZ _)

def prependA(s: String): String = {
  s"A${s}"
}

spark.udf.register("prependAUdf", prependA _)

val hobbiesDf = Seq(
  ("dance"),
  ("sing")
).toDF("word")

val actualDf = hobbiesDf.withColumn(
  "fun",
  col("word").chainUDF("appendZUdf").chainUDF("prependAUdf")
)
```

I'd like to update the `chainUDF` method definition so it takes an optional list of `Column` arguments.  Something like this:

```
def appendWord(s: String, word: String): String = {
  s"${s}${word}"
}

spark.udf.register("appendWordUdf", appendWord _)

val hobbiesDf = Seq(
  ("dance"),
  ("sing")
).toDF("word")

val actualDf = hobbiesDf.withColumn(
  "fun",
  col("word").chainUDF("appendZUdf").chainUDF("appendWordUdf", lit("cool"))
)
```

I think we'll need to update the `chainUDF` method definition to something like this:

```
object ColumnExt {

  implicit class ColumnMethods(c: Column) {

    def chainUDF(udfName: String, cols: Column* = some_default_value): Column = {
      callUDF(udfName, c + cols)
    }

  }

}
```

I'm sure there is some Scala magic trick to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature is:

```
def callUDF(udfName: String, cols: Column*): Column
```

so you don't need magic:

```
def chainUDF(udfName: String, cols: Column* = some_default_value): Column = {
  callUDF(udfName, c +: cols: _*)
}
```

Comment: Your answer works if `= some_default_value` is removed.  I'd be awesome if you could add a little description on how `c +: cols: _*)` works.  Thanks!